# How to Substring a NSString in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, substring

How can I remove all dollar($) symbols from my NSString?

```
amountDataArray = 
    [[NSMutableArray alloc]
         initWithObjects:@"$ 10", @"$ 20", @"$ 30", @"$ 40", @"$ 50", @"$ 60", nil];
```

I am showing displaying string  in `UILabel`:

```
confirm.balanceStr = self.amountLbl.text;
```

I am also setting `amountLbl.text` to `confirm.balanceStr`, but I don't want '$' in my string.

I want to show only amount like 20, 30 , 40 but not with the dollar, like $10, $20,

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
amountLbl.text = [confirm.balanceStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$ " withString:@""];
```

Comment: Welcome. You can always accept the answer if it had worked for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions:

1. String operations, if there is no doubt, that the string has the prefix `@"$ "`:

   `NSString *valueString = [dollaredString substringFromIndex:2];`
2. Scanning. A little bit more robust, but more work to do.
3. Number formatter.

Build a number formatter for your string and let it make the work. You simply have to confgure it to your format.

Answer (score 0):

```
confirm.balanceStr = [self.amountLbl.text replaceOccurencesOfString:@"$" 
                               withString:@"" 
                                  options:NULL
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [receiver length])];
```

Try this code...

Comment: This is wrong since replaceOccurencesOfString is on NSMutableString, not NSString

Answer (score 0):

```
lbl.text = [[yourStringWithDollor componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1];
```